# How to customize the color scheme in Uxrvt?

Tags: colors, rxvt

Different colors are assigned to different text. For instance, in the default Ubuntu color scheme, directories are blue, regular text is gray-white, executable files are green and so on. How to provide such a mapping in urxvt?

I tried changing the values of colors 0 through 15 (`color0` to `color15), but I'm having a hard time figuring out which color number is used for what. However, I am having the feeling that this isn't the right way to do it.

There is nothing anything straight forward in the ArchWiki pages (or anywhere in the net as far as I tried).  How to map colors to how they are used in the `.Xresources` file?

OS: Manjaro Linux with i3 DE

Comment: You have attributed the colour scheme to three different things, none of which are actually the program whose colour scheme this is.  Look at what program you ran.  State it in the question.  Then you'll be a lot closer to finding out how to change its colour scheme (which, if my suspicion is correct, is actually in this program's manual page).

Comment: `echo $LS_COLORS`

Comment: @IporSircer Thank you for the comment. `echo $LS_COLORS` gives a long list of assignments separated by colons. It looks like a mapping to file types and a number that is associated with a color. Is there a standard way to assign it?

Answer (score 0):

Standard way is to add something like

```
color0: *yourColor*
```

to your .Xresources. There is a website called terminal.sexy where you can pick your preferred colors and export them for .Xresources.
After setting the colors, run

```
xrdb -m .Xresources
```